# Should I use protocols when polymorphy is not (yet) an issue?

Tags: clojure

I rarely used protocols yet so I haven't quite got a feeling for using them properly. To me they seem pretty much like Java interfaces with the advantage of having types and operations nicely separated.

Besides solving the expression problem I understand protocols as a way to group functionality in a meaningful way.

So if I have a record and a group of related functions to operate on that record I could define a protocol. But if I don't have any other data types participating in that protocol it somehow feels like misusing the pattern. Besides, isn't it adding unnecessary complexity?

Is there any reasoning about that question or at least some convention on when to use protocols and when to stick with plain old functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My short and opinionated answer would have to be no.

In my Opinion if you aren't going to have other types participating in the protocol then it is not worth the minor inconvenience of using protocols. **Instances of protocols do not automatically reload** when you reload the file defining the protocol which gets a little confusing. If you are going to have code elsewhere participate in the protocol, or even reasonably believe that you might do this they are worth it, though in your case I would have to say no.

My convention/rule-of-thumb:
Stick to plain old functions until you think you can spot the beginnings of the expression problem, then use protocols.